# Running a Command using sshpass

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh

I am trying to run a command using sshpass in a bash script to another linux server.

```
kernel_ipv4=1.2.3.4
vmpassword=dfbvndfbnpdp

    sshpass -p "$vmpassword" ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" root@$kernel_ipv4 'apt update && apt upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install build-essential libncurses-dev bison flex libssl-dev libelf-dev -y && \
    wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/linux-$kernel_version.tar.xz && \
    unxz -v /root/linux-$kernel_version.tar.xz && \
    tar xvf /root/linux-$kernel_version.tar && \
    cp -v /boot/config-$(uname -r) /root/linux-${kernel_version}/.config'
```

The problem here is that when I put all the commands in single quote; then the value of variable ${kernel_version} is not passed.
When I put all the commands in double quotes; then the value of `(uname -r)` is taken of the current server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about double quotes?

```sh
kernel_ipv4=1.2.3.4
vmpassword=dfbvndfbnpdp

    sshpass -p "$vmpassword" ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" root@$kernel_ipv4 "apt update && apt upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install build-essential libncurses-dev bison flex libssl-dev libelf-dev -y && \
    wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/linux-\$kernel_version.tar.xz && \
    unxz -v /root/linux-\$kernel_version.tar.xz && \
    tar xvf /root/linux-\$kernel_version.tar && \
    cp -v /boot/config-\$(uname -r) /root/linux-\${kernel_version}/.config"
```

As you have many commands, I'd use a script

```sh
kernel_ipv4=1.2.3.4
vmpassword=dfbvndfbnpdp

    sshpass -p "$vmpassword" ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" root@$kernel_ipv4 'bash -s' < update_script
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different quoting where appropriate:

```
sshpass -p "$vmpassword" ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" root@$kernel_ipv4 "apt update && apt upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install build-essential libncurses-dev bison flex libssl-dev libelf-dev -y && \
    wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v6.x/linux-$kernel_version.tar.xz && \
    unxz -v /root/linux-$kernel_version.tar.xz && \
    tar xvf /root/linux-$kernel_version.tar && \
    cp -v /boot/config-"'$(uname -r)'" /root/linux-${kernel_version}/.config"
```

Or even, just use double quotes and put an backslash (`\`) before `$(uname -r)`.